# Pandas date convesrion unconverted data remains

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In Pandas (Juypter) I have a column with dates in string format:

```
koncerti.Date.values[:20]
array(['15 September 2010', '16 September 2010', '18 September 2010',
       '20 September 2010', '21 September 2010', '23 September 2010',
       '24 September 2010', '26 September 2010', '28 September 2010',
       '30 September 2010', '1 October 2010', '3 October 2010',
       '5 October 2010', '6 October 2010', '8 October 2010',
       '10 October 2010', '12 October 2010', '13 October 2010',
       '15 October 2010', '17 October 2010'], dtype=object)
```

I try to convert them to date format with the following statement:

```
koncerti.Date = pd.to_datetime(koncerti.Date, format='%d %B %Y')
```

Unfortunatelly, it produces the following error: ValueError: **unconverted data remains: [31]**

What does it mean this error?

Comment: It means some dates do not have the specified formats: https://cumsum.wordpress.com/2020/09/23/pandas-valueerror-unconverted-data-remains/

Comment: The error basically says there is a `bad line` that couldn't be converted on row 31. It would make more sense if you shared that line, but nevertheless it is a safer idea to replace spaces with commas and alter the format accordingly

Comment: Looks good: koncerti.Date.values[31]
koncerti.Date.values[31]
'8 November 2010'

Comment: `unconverted data remains: [31]` means there's a string which has `[31]` in it which does not match the format. To find which is the data you can follow the steps mentioned in https://cumsum.wordpress.com/2020/09/23/pandas-valueerror-unconverted-data-remains/

Comment: Solved. I added ```exact=False``` parameter. Solution ```koncerti.Date = pd.to_datetime(koncerti.Date, format='%d %B %Y', exact=False)```

Comment: `exact=False` will ignore that value hence you will lose it. If it's fine for you you are good to go. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
koncerti.Date = pd.to_datetime(koncerti.Date, format='%d %B %Y', exact=False)
```

Additional parameter was needed: `exact=False`